# Points to Armature?

Tags: armature

I have an animation that's done in points that I want to automatically change to bones which I then want to put into a 3d model of a person so I can animate it. I realize I can just add the bones myself to the model, but since this already has the animation done this would save me from re-doing it. Is it even possible? I'm new to Blender and I've been doing a lot of searching for the answer. The only thing I found was from 3 years ago and that plugin no longer works.

Below is a pictures of what I have. It's a person.

[image: Points in Blender]

Comment: I know this is old but here's my 2 cents. If every point in your data set knows to what point it is parented, then you can write a python script that will build the armature and animate it by keyframing every time stamp in your data. You could also do the opposite and use the skin modifier (but you would need to have edges, not only points) and then build the armature from the modifier – it's an option in the modifier itself.